# Is disk space consumed when storing null data?

Tags: database, sqlite, null, diskspace

I use the sqlite database.
When adding records, disk space is obviously used for non null data. But what about data records that contain null values?
Why Im asking is that I will have a large number of columns (50+) and millions of records that will contain null data and Im wondering if its the most efficient way of designing my database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In SQLite's [record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format), exactly one byte is need to specify that a value is `NULL`.

If you normalize your database so that you have one record per non-`NULL` value, you save those `NULL` bytes, but you have additional overhead for the non-`NULL` values.
SQLite's minimum record overhead [is](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#cell_payload):

- two bytes cell pointer,
- at least one byte payload length,
- several bytes for the `rowid`, and
- for your case, several bytes for the foreign key that points back to the original record.

Additionally, storing non-`NULL` values in a separate table might require an index to get efficient lookups.